# Failed lock verification

Tags: java, android

I've been getting this error every time my app starts and [someone told me](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1393#thread-subscription-status) that it has something to do with `synchronized` in java. However, I'm am not using that directly (though pretty much every library in my app does). I don't know where to start and what code I should be posting. Any ideas?

Here you can see some of my logs with a bunch of different libraries complaining:

```
08-06 20:04:52.287 14696-14696/com.supercilex.robotscouter.debug I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
08-06 20:04:52.323 14696-14705/com.supercilex.robotscouter.debug E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
08-06 20:04:52.323 14696-14705/com.supercilex.robotscouter.debug I/art: Debugger is no longer active
08-06 20:04:52.323 14696-14705/com.supercilex.robotscouter.debug I/art: Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation
08-06 20:04:52.386 14696-14696/com.supercilex.robotscouter.debug W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.supercilex.robotscouter.debug-2/lib/arm64
08-06 20:04:55.309 14696-14696/com.supercilex.robotscouter.debug W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.supercilex.robotscouter.debug-2/lib/arm64
08-06 20:04:55.372 14696-14696/com.supercilex.robotscouter.debug W/art: Class com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp failed lock verification and will run slower.
08-06 20:04:55.372 14696-14696/com.supercilex.robotscouter.debug W/art: Common causes for lock verification issues are non-optimized dex code
08-06 20:04:55.372 14696-14696/com.supercilex.robotscouter.debug W/art: and incorrect proguard optimizations.
08-06 20:04:55.381 14696-14696/com.supercilex.robotscouter.debug W/art: Class android.support.v4.util.SimpleArrayMap failed lock verification and will run slower.
08-06 20:04:55.454 14696-14696/com.supercilex.robotscouter.debug W/art: Class com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient failed lock verification and will run slower.
08-06 20:04:55.474 14696-14696/com.supercilex.robotscouter.debug W/art: Class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqc failed lock verification and will run slower.
08-06 20:04:55.507 14696-14965/com.supercilex.robotscouter.debug W/art: Class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqc$zzc failed lock verification and will run slower.
08-06 20:04:55.519 14696-14965/com.supercilex.robotscouter.debug W/art: Class com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder failed lock verification and will run slower.
08-06 20:04:55.533 14696-14965/com.supercilex.robotscouter.debug W/art: Class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd failed lock verification and will run slower.
08-06 20:04:55.540 14696-14965/com.supercilex.robotscouter.debug W/art: Class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzm failed lock verification and will run slower.
08-06 20:04:55.542 14696-14965/com.supercilex.robotscouter.debug W/art: Class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzn failed lock verification and will run slower.
08-06 20:04:55.548 14696-14965/com.supercilex.robotscouter.debug W/art: Class com.google.android.gms.common.stats.zzb failed lock verification and will run slower.
08-06 20:04:55.557 14696-14965/com.supercilex.robotscouter.debug W/art: Class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzsb failed lock verification and will run slower.
08-06 20:04:55.558 14696-14965/com.supercilex.robotscouter.debug W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
08-06 20:04:55.561 14696-14965/com.supercilex.robotscouter.debug W/art: Class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzz failed lock verification and will run slower.
08-06 20:04:55.566 14696-14965/com.supercilex.robotscouter.debug W/art: Class com.google.android.gms.common.zzf failed lock verification and will run slower.
08-06 20:04:55.567 14696-14965/com.supercilex.robotscouter.debug W/art: Class com.google.android.gms.common.zzd$zzc failed lock verification and will run slower.
08-06 20:04:55.571 14696-14965/com.supercilex.robotscouter.debug W/art: Class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd$zzh failed lock verification and will run slower.
```

Comment: seeing the same message for different classes, Basically I've found where it is coming from, check line 328: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/art/+/3188364/runtime/verifier/method_verifier.cc   
However I lack the required c++ knowledge to fully understand what the thing does. But they stated in the comments that `Common causes for lock verification issues are non-optimized dex code and incorrect proguard optimizations.`

Answer (score 4):

It happens to me on a Nexus 6P and Android 7.0 final release. There is an opened bug for this issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=219490